# Can I use "that of" when comparing an adverbial phrase?

Tags: word-usage, adverbial-phrases

I am not really sure that I know how to use the words "that of".

I wrote this example:

> Travelling long distances by plane is faster than **that of** train.

Is this okay?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the same preposition with prepositional phrases joined by *than*:

> Travelling long distances by plane is faster **than by** train.

Though you could say:

> The speed of a plane is faster **than that of** a train.

In the first example you are comparing prepositional phrases (by plane, by train). In the second one you are comparing the subject noun (speed),

Comment: Did you accidentally hit submit before your answer was complete?  It looks like the rest of the sentence should read something like ", with the speed of a train, with the pronoun *that* standing in for *speed*."